# Unable to Upload/Download files using SCP from a Cisco switch configured as SSH server

Tags: c#, ssh, scp, ssh.net

I need to be able to upload and download (configuration) files using SCP from and to a Cisco Switch that is configured to act as an SSH server. This needs to be coded in C#

I started by using the SharpSSH library (Tamir.SharpSSH) wich is pretty straight forward.

```
Scp scp = null;
    try
    {
        scp = new Scp(Switch.Ip, Switch.User, Switch.Password);
        scp.Timeout = Switch.Timeout;
        scp.Connect();
        if (scp.Connected)
        {
            scp.Get(@"flash:/scp/test.txt", @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop");
            scp.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {}
```

This code should download the "test.txt" file from the remote SSH server to the local desktop. But everytime I try to exectue this code I get the error "scp: "flash:/scp/test.txt": No such file or directory" even though this is clearly a directory and file on the server as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2t3D.png).

After this I gave up on sharpSSH and tried the SSH.NET (Renci.SshNet) library hoping this would give me better results. But no luck. using the code below

```
ScpClient scp = null;
    try
    {
        scp = new ScpClient(Switch.Ip, Switch.User, Switch.Password);
        scp.Connect();
        if (scp.IsConnected)
        {
            scp.Download(@"flash:/scp/test.txt", new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"));
            scp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
```

But this gave me the error "-p -r -d options not supported".
at this moment I just don't know what to try anymore.
I also tested the SSH.NET library localy with a setup Bitvise SSH server where I was able to succesfully upload and download files. 
I'm clueless what could be the problem.

Edit: The local code I tested that worked with the SSH.NET library and the Bitvise SSH server. Bitvise root directory is "/" where I made a map scp with a text.txt file inside. So to be clear the flash:/ directory is not applicable here as this only exists on the cisco switch and I did not recreate this on the Bitvise server.

```
       if (scp.IsConnected)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("SCP CONNECTED");

            if (type == "download")
            {
                scp.Download(@"/scp/test.txt", new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop"));
                System.Console.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD SUCCEEDED");

                scp.Disconnect();
                System.Console.WriteLine("SCP DISCONNECTED");
            }
         }
```

Comment: Getting errors is pretty good considering you have empty `catch` blocks!

Comment: Can you copy files from this cisco device using the command-line scp utility? Could you [edit] your question to show an example of running the scp command successfully?

Comment: @itsme86 I removed the catch block as this wasn't relevant to the problem, sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: If you can construct the syntax from the command line e.g. `scp user@system:flash:scp/test.txt .` and it works then it's everything following the colon for the system name that should be used for the source location. The recni.sshclient uses `sftp` when you ask for an instance of the `scp` client, which is **not the same**, which is why you get the `options not supported` error.

Comment: @Petesh I can indeed do an SCP download using pscp (putty scp) with the following command "pscp -scp user@host:flash:/scp/test.txt". So this proves that the directory "flash:/scp/test.txt" is indeed correct. but it still gives me "flash:/scp/test.txt": No such file or directory" when trying this with scp.get using the SharpSsh library. So not sure what your answer/solution is to this problem. Are you saying there isn't a real SCP in the Renci library? just an instance of sftp they mark as scp?